# Computing the Cheeger constant for a finite graph by hand.

Tags: graph-theory

The **Cheeger constant** for a finite graph $\Gamma$ with vertex set $V(\Gamma)$ is
\begin{align*}
h(\Gamma) = \min\Big\{\frac{\#\partial X}{\# X}\Big\vert X \subseteq V(\Gamma), 0 < \# X \leq \frac{1}{2}\#V(\Gamma)\Big\}.
\end{align*}
I have a small-ish ($17$ vertices and $55$ edges) simple, connected and finite graph $\Gamma$ and I would like to compute its Cheeger constant. Here is what I have explored thus far.

- By considering sets $X$ with two vertices, I have the bound $h(\Gamma) \leq 7/2$.
- By considering $3$-cliques and independent sets with three vertices I have $h(\Gamma) \leq 10/3$.
- I have shown that no independent set can improve the $10/3$ bound.
- I have shown that no $4$-clique can improve the $10/3$ bound.
- By considering a set $X$ which is almost a $4$-clique, I have the bound $h(\Gamma) \leq 3$.

I would like to know if there are any methods or inequalities that I can use to improve the bound $h(\Gamma) \leq 3$ or bound $h(\Gamma)$ below. I have already computed many other graph invariants that I can use in my calculations: clique number, independence number, dominance number etc.

Comment: What graph (17 vertices and 55 edges) are you thinking of? Why not consider a computer program to deal with a graph of small order.

Comment: This is a homework assignment in which I am to calculate or bound all of these invariants by hand. I didn't want to provide the specific graph, because I just wanted some methods or inequalities that I could use and not a fully worked out answer

Answer (score 2):

Since OP did not provide a specific graph, I have to  generate a random graph with 17 vertices and 55 edges. For specific small order graph, we can use sage to handle them. As for the manual method, since the graph is not given, it is not easy to discover some structure for computing the Cheeger constant for a random graph.

```
g=graphs.RandomGNM(17, 55)
g.edges(sort=True, labels=False) # edge list
g.show()
g.cheeger_constant() # cheeger constant
```

[image]

> [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 7), (0, 10), (0, 11), (0, 14), (0, 16), (1, 9),
> (1, 12), (1, 15), (1, 16), (2, 4), (2, 7), (2, 11), (2, 16), (3, 5),
> (3, 9), (3, 11), (3, 12), (3, 14), (3, 16), (4, 6), (4, 9), (4, 11),
> (4, 13), (4, 15), (5, 8), (5, 9), (5, 12), (5, 14), (5, 15), (5, 16),
> (6, 7), (6, 8), (6, 9), (6, 11), (6, 15), (7, 10), (7, 11), (7, 12),
> (7, 13), (8, 11), (8, 14), (9, 10), (9, 11), (9, 15), (10, 12), (10,
> 15), (11, 12), (11, 15), (11, 16), (12, 13), (12, 16), (13, 14), (14,
> 16)]

$$\frac{19}{55}$$

---

or:

```
from sage.combinat.subset import Subsets
g=Graph([(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 7), (0, 10), (0, 11), (0, 14), (0, 16), (1, 9), (1, 12), (1, 15), (1, 16), (2, 4), (2, 7), (2, 11), (2, 16), (3, 5), (3, 9), (3, 11), (3, 12), (3, 14), (3, 16), (4, 6), (4, 9), (4, 11), (4, 13), (4, 15), (5, 8), (5, 9), (5, 12), (5, 14), (5, 15), (5, 16), (6, 7), (6, 8), (6, 9), (6, 11), (6, 15), (7, 10), (7, 11), (7, 12), (7, 13), (8, 11), (8, 14), (9, 10), (9, 11), (9, 15), (10, 12), (10, 15), (11, 12), (11, 15), (11, 16), (12, 13), (12, 16), (13, 14), (14, 16)])
def cheegerconstant(self):
        c = 10000000
        e = self.num_edges()
        for s in Subsets(self.vertices(sort=True)):
            vol = sum(self.degree(s))
            if not vol:
                continue
            if vol > e:
                continue
            boundary = len(self.edge_boundary(s))
            n = Integer(boundary) / Integer(vol)
            if n < c:
                c = n
        return c
cheegerconstant(g)
```

$$\frac{19}{55}$$

Comment: While this wasn't what I was originally after (so I cannot accept this answer), it does give me an indication of how large I should expect the Cheeger constant to be so thank you very much

Comment: Without a specific graph, I guess it's hard for others to give you what you want. Unless you want to get some general methods of estimating the bounds of  graphs.

Comment: I am looking for general methods, yes. Especially ones involving the values of other invariants or knowledge of special sets (independent sets, cliques etc.). For example if I know some $k$-cliques it can be enough to show that no $k$-colouring exists.